# How can I dynamically remove some unwanted formatting tags inside rich text fields?

Tags: control-panel, redactor, richtext

I set up a Redactor config to add h3 headings only. If I copy-paste texts from a text edition software like Microsoft Word and uses h1 or h2 for example in his document, these un-wanted headings will be pasted in the rich text field. In another way, if I add an heading tag like `<h1>` in the source code mode of Redactor, this unwanted heading will also be added.

**How can I prevent this and set a list of unwanted tags that could be dynamically deleted or converted in `<p>` ?**

There are *pasteBlockTags* and *pasteInlineTags* options in the Redactor doc (https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/paste/#setting-pasteBlockTags), but it doesn't seems possible to add these options inside the JSON file stored in `craft/config/redactor`.

I also tried to add a new *formattingAdd* option, which I called Remove format, and replace unwanted tags by `<p>`, but this is an annoying solution because it needs to review each pieces of texts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a "real" answer because it won't fix your actual content, but I wrote [a plugin](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft) that would make it easy to remedy your issue on the front end (i.e. in the template) –

To remove all `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags (content inside tags will not be removed):

```
{{ entry.someRedactorField|retconChange(['h1','h2'], false) }}
```

To change `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags into `<p>` tags:

```
{{ entry.someRedactorField|retconChange(['h1','h2'], 'p') }}
```

You can read more about the `rectonChange` filter used in the two examples above [here](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft/wiki/Change).